# Python: Use numpy flip with memmap

Tags: python, numpy

I writting large array so I'm using [numpy memmap](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html)

At the end of my operation I would like to use flip function but the problem is, the flip function does not apply after using the flush function on memap

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Create array on disk

fpc = np.memmap("test3.rgb", dtype=np.uint8, mode='w+', shape=(10000,20000,3))
fpc[0:5000] = [255,0,0]     #Top red
fpc[5000:10000] = [0,255,0] #Bottom green


plt.subplot(131)
plt.title("Before flip")
plt.imshow(fpc)


#Apply flip function, so green come on top
fpc = np.flip(fpc,0)

plt.subplot(132)
plt.imshow(fpc)
plt.title("After flip")

#Save changes
fpc.flush()

#Reload array
fpc = np.memmap("test3.rgb", dtype=np.uint8, mode='r', shape=(10000,20000,3))


plt.subplot(133)
plt.title("After reload")
plt.imshow(fpc)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Is it really possible to use memmap with a flip function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.flip` creates a new array in memory. You need to set the one mapped to the file. The current code only change the reference of `fpc` so to reference the new array. You can fix that with:

```py
fpc[:,:] = np.flip(fpc,0)
```

**UPDATE:** note that if you use `memmap` to reduce the memory footprint, then doing a `np.flip` will defeat this optimization since a new array is created anyway. You can *swap pairs of lines manually* so to reduce the memory footprint. For better performance, you can **flip&swap chunks of lines**.